# How can I add router in remote actors?

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I already included this in my application.conf but it's not working:

```
akka {
    actor {
        provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
            deployment {
                /messageSender {
                    router = "round-robin"
                    nr-of-instances = 10
                    target {
                        nodes = "akka://System@127.0.0.1:5555"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        remote {
            transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
    }
}
```

Comment: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/scala/routing.html#Remotely_Deploying_Routees

Comment: @ViktorKlang Thanks! I'm just starting to familiarize myself in using akka. :)

Comment: Read the docs a couple of times, it's about 350 pages :-)